# How to scraping multile website with c# but dont interact with DOM or analyze it into feature object

Tags: c#, screen-scraping

I want to scraping website by c# but i just can take content from DOM. I want to take content up to 1000 website so i can't select content by choose the class and take innertext. Can i use library or tool to analyze html and it will give me some feature object as price, title, description, old price? And how can i do it. Thank you

I try use puppeteer and HtmlAgilityPack but i only know interact with DOM and i can't do that with 1000 website with different struct

If i use code like that, i only can scrape from 1 website

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using PuppeteerSharp;

namespace CrawlData
{
    internal class CrawlData
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var crawlData = new CrawlData();
            await crawlData.myCrawl();
        }
        public async Task<String> myCrawl()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("URL:");
            var url = Console.ReadLine();
            using var browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher();
            await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync();
            await using var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions { Headless = true, ExecutablePath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" });
            await using var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
            await page.GoToAsync(url);
            var price = await page.QuerySelectorAllAsync(".price");
            foreach (var priceElement in price)
            {
                var result = await priceElement.EvaluateFunctionAsync("element => element.textContent");
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```